# Statistics on open source growth (or decline)?

Tags: commercial, community

I'm trying to find some data regarding general open source usage and adoption over time. My own impression is that usage and development of open source software is getting more and more common but i don't seem to find any data to support or negate this impression.

Where can i find any good reference regarding the growth of open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some slides from a study, conducted in 2015 with quite impressive numbers https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/North_Bridge/2015-future-of-open-source-study

This are two additional studies/articles from 2017 which show a similar trend:
http://opensourcesurvey.org/2017/
https://itsfoss.com/open-source-adoption-europe/